# 3D graphics - vector math, I seem to get something wrong

Tags: math, graphics, 3d

The goal is to get a point in 3D space projected on the cameras screen (the final goal is to produce a points cloud)

This is the setup:

Camera
postion: px,py,pz
up direction: ux,uy,uz
look_at_direction: lx,ly,lz
screen_width
screen_height
screen_dist

Point in space:
p = (x,y,z)

And

init U,V,W

```
w = || position - look_at_direction || = || (px,py,pz) - (ux,uy,uz) ||
u = || (ux,uy,uz) cross-product w ||
v = || w cross-product u ||
```

This gives me the u,v,w coords of the camera.

This are the steps I'm supposed to implement, and the way I understand them. I believe something was lost in the translation.

(1) Find the ray from the camera to the point

I subtract the point with the camera's position

ray_to_point = p - position

(2) Calculate the dot product between the ray to the point and the normalized ray
to the center of the screen (the camera direction). Divide the result by sc_dist.
This will give you a ratio between the distance of the point and the distance to the camera's screen.

ratio = (ray_to_point * w)/screen_dist

Here I'm not sure I should be using w or the original look at value of the camera or the w vector which is the unit vector in the camera's space.

(3) Divide the ray to the point by the ratio found in step 2, and add it to the camera position. This will give you the projection of the point on the camera screen.
point_on_camera_screen = ray_to_point / ratio

(4) Find a vector between the center of the camera's screen and the projected point.
Am I supposed to find the center pixel of the screen? How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: screen_coords = projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * your_vector_in_3d_space     (that might be back to front)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following figure:

[image: Figure]

The first step is to calculate the difference vector from camera to p`(=>`diff`). That's correct.

The next step is to express the difference vector in the camera's coordinate system. Since its axes are orthogonal, this can be done with the dot product. Be sure that the axes are unit vectors:

```
diffInCameraSpace = (dot(diff, u), dot(diff, v), dot(diff, w))
```

Now comes the scaling part so that the resulting difference vector has a z-component of `screen_dist`. So:

```
diffInCameraSpace *= screenDist / diffInCameraSpace.z
```

You don't want to transform it back to world space. You might need some further information on how camera units are mapped to pixels, but at this step you are basically done. You might want to shift the resulting `diffInCameraSpace` by `(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2, 0)`. Forget the z-component and you have the position on the screen.